# How to Download Specific Region from OSM

Tags: maps, openstreetmap

I'm new to using Open Street Maps, and I'm not familiar with all the tooling involved. I'm attempting to make a specialized navigation tool, but I need to download specific regions from Open Street Maps in order to have the map data. I need specific regions, much like how my [company's maps currently are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUJmA.png).

That being the case, how would I accomplish this, can it be accomplished, what tools are available to do so?